# Package executes successfully, SQL Agent executes the job successfully but the file isn't loaded to the DB and being transferred

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreach, ssis, sql-agent-job

I have a package in SSIS that loads 3 excel files into a table:
once the loading is finished, I use a table to track the load time + the amount of loaded data, After that I transfer the files via FileTaskSystem and ForEach Container.
This is my package:
[image]

it works perfectly when I execute it in SSIS and the this is the output in the transfertable:

[image]

and moreover, the files are transferred to the destination.

When I execute that package in the SSMS via SQL Agent it works but it doesn't load the data inside the mrrMashbir3 and mrrMega tables.
The only thing that works is the RetailerContainer which is not inside ForeachLoop
[image]

As you can see, all the actions that were in the Foreach didn't work (neither the file transferring).

Comment: Did you consult the SSISDB logs? They will very likely give you plenty of informative information. What about the logs didn't you understand?

Comment: I think the answer by @billinkc will most likely solve your issue by using the UNC path. just a note to your package design, not sure the actual work flow, but by looking at tasks, you may want to GROUP all those 3 tasks together after the 1st truncate table task to force the execution sequence in order.

Answer (score 1):

The Foreach File enumerator will raise an Informational event when it cannot list the contents of a folder. Not an error, just a simple "I didn't find any files here"

As the process works when "you" run it but does not when the "SQL Agent" account runs it, the most probable issue is that account does not have permissions to the path. Less likely is that the path does not exist - i.e. development uses a mapped drive D: which is really \server\share\data which your account auto maps but the agent account does not.

Resolution is going to be dependent on the root cause but probably takes the form of one of the following

- Create a credentialed user in SQL Server, assign permissions to the credential for the SSIS subsystem and then update the job step to use the credentialed user
- Identify the user that is the SQL Agent account and Assign ACL/file system permissions to the folder with source data
- Add a precursor/successor batch script to the Agent job to Map and unmap the network location
- Add/update the Configuration for the SSIS package to use a UNC path versus a mapped drive

Check your SSIS log for Information events, you'll likely see one from the `Mashbir Foreach` and if the above options don't resolve it, edit your question with the specific details (account that is running the package, where the foreach enumerators are pointed to, etc) and then comment on this answer and I'll check back.